# What the expected temperature veration between shelfs in a fan oven?

Tags: oven

When a fan oven is set to 200c, what is an reasonable range of temperatures to expect on each shelf?

I have a tenant complaining then does not cook correctly and when I measured the temperature, the top shelf gives 180 and the middle shelf 160, with the bottom shelf at 150.  I have replaced the thermostat and the fan seems to be working OK.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't the point of a convection oven to move the air around and create a more consistent environment in the oven?  People get caught up with the idea that an oven needs to be precise, when, in fact, very few ovens are accurate (with respect to the number on the dial and the actual internal temperature), and it is not uncommon for the temperature to range significantly within a cooking cycle.  It is also not uncommon for the temperature of a standard oven (no convection) to range in different places within the oven.  Ovens are not precision devices.  In fact, [some argue that we should stop worrying about exact oven temperature](https://www.thekitchn.com/why-you-should-stop-worrying-about-your-oven-temperature-175602) (I whole hardheartedly agree), and just think in terms of three or four basic ranges (low, medium, high...or...really low, low, medium, and high).  The article specifies the temperature ranges.  Nothing that is cooked in an oven requires more specificity than this.

It seems to me, you've gone above and beyond to please your tenant.  Now, it is up to them to understand oven cookery.

Comment: They claim that oven is cooking a lot slower then it was 6 months ago, I wish I had data to know if it truely is.